# How to configure test_pattern for mix test

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I'd like to change the `test_pattern` for `mix test` but I'm having trouble figuring out the right way to perform this configuration. I tried a number of variants of configuration in `config/test.exs` but never figured it out. Eventually I found that changing `mix.exs` (which I think is the highest level config file) worked:

```
defmodule Server.Mixfile do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [
      app: :server,
      version: "0.0.1",
      elixir: "~> 1.4",
      elixirc_paths: elixirc_paths(Mix.env),
      compilers: [:phoenix, :gettext] ++ Mix.compilers,
      start_permanent: Mix.env == :prod,
      aliases: aliases(),
      deps: deps(),
      test_pattern: "*_test.ex", # ----- this is what worked!
    ]
  end

  # more config stuff
end
```

What's the right way to perform configuration for `mix test`?

I came across this hack by looking at [this LOC](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/mix/lib/mix/tasks/test.ex#L263) and trying to get my project config to conform to that check. I suspect there's a better way to achieve what I want.

Here's what my `config/test.exs` file looks like right now (with some comments)

```
use Mix.Config

# We don't run a server during test. If one is required,
# you can enable the server option below.
config :server,
       ServerWeb.Endpoint,
       http: [
         port: 4001
       ],
       server: false

# Print only warnings and errors during test
config :logger, level: :warn

config :server,
       Server.Repo,
       adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
       username: System.get_env("POSTGRES_USER") || "postgres",
       password: System.get_env("POSTGRES_PASSWORD") || "postgres",
       database: System.get_env("POSTGRES_DB") || "postgres",
       hostname: System.get_env("POSTGRES_HOST") || "localhost",
       pool: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox
       # test_pattern: "*_test.ex" ---- this doesn't get picked up

#config :project, ------------- this complains about the application "project" not being available
#       test_pattern: "*_test.exs?"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you expect that changing anything in `config :server` would result in side-effects? [`Mix.Config.config/3`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.6.4/lib/mix/lib/mix/config.ex#L115) is a simple macro that stores the value(s) in the configuration storage for future use. It does not execute any code nor has any side-effects.

Even more, the section you were trying to put the `test_pattern` key is for `Server.Repo`, which is read by [`Ecto.Repo`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#content) and the latter knows nothing about how to handle `test_pattern` key and effectively ignores it.

As a side note I’d say that changing test pattern to include compiled `*.ex` files does not sound like a very good idea in general; these files will be 1) compiled and 2) included in the release by default. They have `*.exs` extension on purpose: the trailing “s” stands for “script,” providing the files will be treated as scripts.

Also, if you are still positive you want this pattern, configuring it through `project` configuration is exactly where it belongs. This is not a hack by any means, this is the intended way to change the pattern.

Comment: I'm still extremely new to Elixir and was doing trial and error when I tried setting the configuration for `config :server`. The reason I want to use `.ex` files is because the intellij elixir plugin doesn't allow breaking on `.exs` files. I'm still really new to Elixir and want to set breakpoints in my tests (as part of the learning process). Do you have any suggestions for how else I might be able to debug my tests?

Comment: I am not sure why would you like to debug tests, but I am positive that in learning purposes everything is fine :)

Comment: I need to debug my tests because I'm still not sure that the Elixir code I write (even for tests) is doing what I expect. One day I won't need to debug them :)